# How do I convert a .cdr file to .jpg using imagick API?

Tags: conversion, imagemagick, api

How do I convert a .cdr file to .jpg using imagick API? I have done conversion of .ai and .psd files, but .cdr file isn't working. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What versions of things are you using? Core Draw file, OS, and version of ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Imagemagick's `convert` command? I just tried this on a `Fedora 14` system and got the following error.

```
% convert hotrod_ms50.cdr hotrod_ms50.png
convert: delegate failed `"ffmpeg" -v -1 -vframes %S -i "%i" -vcodec pam -an -f rawvideo -y "%u.pam" 2> "%Z"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1061.
convert: improper image header `/tmp/magick-XXuV37pz.pam' @ error/pnm.c/ReadPNMImage/295.
convert: missing an image filename `hotrod_ms50.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2953.
```

According to this [URL](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=9564&start=0) `Imagemagick` does support the conversion of `.cdr` but it looks like it's using `ffmpeg` to do this. What version of `Corel Draw` is your `.cdr` file from?

The [file](http://vector-images.com/clipart.php?id=19925) I tried to use above was reported to be from `Core Draw 9.`